# Why is Windows XP (32-bit) limited to 3GB of usable memory?

Tags: windows, memory, memory-management

It was written that with windows xp 32 bit the top 700 mb or ram or so was not usable.  But it has also been said that there is no point installing more than 3gb or so. So this leads me to this issue. So is that area reserved by the os actually residing in that ram, or is just using the address space. In other words is the ram physically being filled with 700mb of information, or is 700mb of the cpu' address space being reserved and mapped. Because if it is not, then installing 3gbs would still be a problem, because it would still take away 700mb somehow?

Comment: the maximum address space of a machine having a CPU with 32bit "address bus" can't be more than 4 Gb (2^{32}-1), consider also that the address space usable for memory is not likely the whole range, since there are mapped in the address space also other things that are not "user RAM", so maybe 3 Gb is already "near" the limit; maybe this is the problem

Comment: XP does reserve some address space for the kernel; I'd expect that most of it is not actually backed by physical memory most of the time. However, that does mean that no individual process can use more than about 3GB of address space, hence no more than 3GB of physical ram. The kernel may still be able to use the rest for other purposes, and should be able to use the rest for other processes, so I don't see why you'd go out of your way to avoid putting all 4 GB in.

Comment: Basically what I'm asking is going all the way back to real mode. When the top 300kb or so was reserved.  It's the same issue with 32 bit protected mode I think.  Is there actually data residing in 700mb of ram chips.  Or is it just 700mb os addressable space by the processor being mapped other data or io locations

Comment: (un)real mode does not bear on the question at hand. The answer is that XP does not blather 700MB of data into RAM. This is trivially shown by the fact that XP is capable of running on machines with much less than 700MB of RAM. It's mostly just empty reserved address space.

Comment: zmccord, there's virtual memory, though :)

Comment: I realize that it sound's like that, but what I'm asking is whether or not 700mb of physical memory is being reserved or 700mbs or address space backed by devices other than ram

Comment: @Joey: Alright, then it is trivially shown by the fact that XP is capable of running *well* on machines with much less than 700MB of RAM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

32 bit systems have 4 GB of available address space, but address space is used fo rmore than just system memory. For example, part of video card memory can be mapped into the address space, which reduces the space available for system memory. This is covered in the section "How graphics cards and other devices affect memory limits" of Microsoft's [Memory Limits for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page.

The applicable text is below to preserve for posterity:

> Devices have to map their memory below 4 GB for compatibility with
>   non-PAE-aware Windows releases. Therefore, if the system has 4GB of
>   RAM, some of it is either disabled or is remapped above 4GB by the
>   BIOS. If the memory is remapped, X64 Windows can use this memory. X86
>   client versions of Windows don’t support physical memory above the 4GB
>   mark, so they can’t access these remapped regions. Any X64 Windows or
>   X86 Server release can.

Comment: I guess why I'm confused, is because can't the processor access video memory directly, or can it only map it into it's addressable space? What would be the point of doing that. If it's not in ram, and it can be accessed anyway why would it be useful to reference it like that. Does the processor need to even use it in the first place?

Comment: Its not just about the processor, processes need some way to load data into these regions as well in order to communicate with devices. Working on PCs makes this all very abstract, but with embedded devices (say a GBA) the only way to draw a picture was to write it into the video buffer, which was just a memory address. Sure, there could have been "another mechanism" for performing these operations, but using a single addressing scheme was a simple solution.

Comment: So the basic idea is that 700mb block is not residing physically in ram, but just taking 700mb of the addressable space by cpu. So it would make sense not to install anything greater than 3gbs or so of ram because those address will not be used by ram, but are instead reserved and mapped?

Comment: Correct. The exception is if you run any applications that support PAE, which is an extension that allows them to address additional memory. Its relatively rare, only applications I've used with it are enterprise databases.

Comment: Actually, only the Server editions of IA32 WinXP support PAE anyway, so unless you're using Server you won't get access to the extra address space even then. And as I pointed out before there's nothing preventing you from using all 4 GB of physical RAM, it just can't all be mapped into the same address space.

Answer (score 1):

The OS needs to reserve some physical address space for various functions, such as interrupt handlers, system calls, etc. Those address becomes unusable for programs on the OS.